# Oracle select/update fieldA where fieldA exists Instr(fieldB) of a different table

Tags: sql, oracle

I would like to update a `Table1.field2` where I find `Table1.field1` within `Table2.field1`

Example:

```
UPDATE Table1 t1 
   SET t1.field2 = 'yes' 
 where Instr(t2.field1, Table2.field1) > 0
```

I've tried this a few other ways and I understand my example is definable not the way to do it. I just think it demonstrates best what I'm trying to achieve.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The Join like below would be ending up in cartesian result

```
UPDATE Table1 t1 SET t1.field2 = 'yes' 
where EXISTS
(SELECT 'X' FROM Table2 t2 where Instr(t1.field1, t2.field1) > 0
```

Comment: this seems to work on small test tables. But with large tables the query seems to run forever

Comment: Yes, if your two tables, can't be joined directly, it is going to be hectic... `Instr(t1.field1, t2.field1)` is not a performing joining condition at all..

Answer (score 0):

Use an exists clause.

```
UPDATE Table1 t1
   SET t1.field2 = 'YES'
 WHERE EXISTS
          (SELECT 1
             FROM Table2 t2 
            WHERE t1.primary_key = t2.foreign_key
             and INSTR (t1.field1, t2.field1) > 0);
```

Comment: what is primary_key and foreign_key?

Comment: @user1332534 I'm presuming their is key on both tables they share to make the update appropriate.  (e.g. Customers.customerID and Orders.customerID)  that is what I mean by primary_key and foreign_key - you gave junk/boilerplate schema I give junk column names.

Comment: the primary key of each table will not match

Comment: @user1332534 I'm not suggesting the PK of two different tables 'match'